# Pandas, merge multiple CSV's into one and clean strings

Tags: python, pandas

I am having some issues using pandas to manipulate some files into the right format.

I have multiple CSV's that I want to merge into one file.

They all have this sort of structure,

```
  data1, data2 etc
```

And then with the key values, which are area (ideally want to rename column there), any arearea that has two words in it has looks like this, [![enter image description here][2]][2] , with "%20" instead of a space, and I'd want to remove that %20 ideally.

And lastly, I want to have the arearea have their respective long and lats from this file here,

If anyone has some pointers on achieving this, that would be amazing, I'm stuck using df.merge, and keep receiving errors. So close to achieving getting it complete!

Comment: What is the error, please add it to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat` ([pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)). As for string cleaning, you can apply a lambda function after the fact. Here's an example:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df1


    a   b   c
0   1   2   aardvark
1   3   4   pangolin
2   5   6   cat%20dog

df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
df2

    a   b   c
0   7   8   bus
1   9   10  boat
2   11  12  ferry%20plane

# use pd.concat
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index(drop=True)
df

    a   b   c
0   1   2   aardvark
1   3   4   pangolin
2   5   6   cat%20dog
3   7   8   bus
4   9   10  boat
5   11  12  ferry%20plane

# apply lambda to clean the %20
f = lambda s: s.replace('%20', ' ')
df['clean_c'] = df['c'].apply(f)

df[['a', 'b', 'clean_c']]

    a   b   clean_c
0   1   2   aardvark
1   3   4   pangolin
2   5   6   cat dog
3   7   8   bus
4   9   10  boat
5   11  12  ferry plane
```

Comment: Ideally, you should use `df['clean_c'] = df['c'].str.replace('%20', ' ')`, as the vectorized [series string operator](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings) is much faster than applying a lambda function in large datasets.